# exerciseName is giving me a different output from input[i], when exerciseName is = to input[i] (see code)

Tags: javascript

Some information is missing from my code as i seperated all that i needed to troubleshoot why this was happening. Im a beginner.

In this code exerciseName is outputting *Money* 2 times, input[i] is outputting *Money, Story, Spring Time, Bus* yet exerciseName is = input[i]. Why arent they the same? Im trying to replace input[i] in the while statement with exerciseName doing the same.

```js
function solve(input) {

    let i = 1;
    let exerciseName = input[i];

    while (input[i] !== "Enough") {

        console.log(exerciseName)
        console.log(input[i])
        i += 2

    }
    
}

solve(["3", "Money", "6", "Story", "4", "Spring Time", "5", "Bus", "6", "Enough"])
```

Comment: `exerciseName` isn't an alias of `input[i]`. It is the value `input[i]` had when it was executed. (`input[1]`, so `"Money"` in this case.)

Comment: When you write `let exerciseName = input[i]`, `exerciseName` takes the value of `input[i]` at that moment in time (which is "Money"). `exerciseName` *is not* a reference to `input[i]` that will keep updating whenever `i` is also updated. With this code `exerciseName` is always equal to "Money". Assigning with `=` does not some how "link" the two together. Why do you want to replace `input[i]`?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

`exerciseName` is always pointing to `input[1]`

`exerciseName` is not outputing `Money` 2 times.

It is the sequence

1. `exerciseName` being equal to `input[1]` (Money)
2. `input[1]`
3. next iteration `exerciseName` which is still equal to `Money`.

You must set it everytime inside your loop if you want your value to change.

Comment: i saw afterwards that `exerciseName` stayed referencing `input[1]` only.